# If i click social media buttons of Heise Shariff from tx_news i get 404 error

Tags: typo3, tx-news

The URL is only partly transferred: `https://....org/artikel/`

Any idea how to solve this? Any other information needed?

Latest TYPO3 version 7.6.11, tx_news 5.2 and rx_shariff 9.0.0

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was the canonical tag the missing `addQueryString` (thanks for the hint to Georg Ringer)

Here is my working code:

```
page.headerData {
    700 = TEXT
    700 {
    stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = TSFE:id
    stdWrap.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
    stdWrap.typolink.returnLast = url
    stdWrap.typolink.parameter.intval = 1
    stdWrap.typolink.useCacheHash = 1
    stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString = 1
    stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString.method = GET
    stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString.exclude = id, cHash 
    htmlSpecialChars = 1
    wrap = <link href="|" rel="canonical" />
  }
}
```

Comment: To make things clear, you're using the above mentioned snippet for your whole website - not just the news detail page?

Comment: @josef-glatz 

Yes, and as i can see it works well on all pages.